# Optaplanner Shadow variable

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am using "chained through time pattern" for our optimization project where following the example TaskAssignment but for the shadow variable instead of using Integer start time, using TimeGrain (from meeting example).

The Domain Problem is: for each Schedule (within a day) one or more Service (PlanningEntity) need to be assigned one after another immediately after the previous one is completed.

Here, I am using TimeGrain as a shadow variable (because availability of the resources are defined for each TimeGrain)

```
@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = AssignmentVariableListener.class,
                           sources = { @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "previousAssignment"), 
                                       @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "scheduleAssignment")
                                      }
                          )
public TimeGrain getTimeGrain() {
    return timeGrain;
}
```

I am setting the shadow variable in the variable listener, but do I have to always initialize the shadow variable first before start solving ?

In the TaskAssignment example, the end time is calculated based on the start time, but the start time initially would be null. How does this get initialized ?

Thank you,
Karthik

Comment: If "the shadow variable A = genuine variable B + 10", then if you give a solution instance to optaplanner for which B is 4 and A is not 14 (for example null), you're giving it a corrupted instance and it will behave badly. Turn on environmentMode FULL_ASSERT and it will spend cpu cycles to validate that.

Comment: OptaPlanner guarantees that as it changes the genuine variable B, it will call the listener to allow it to update A. So it won't corrupt the model.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey for your quick answer, your second update answer my question and I will change the env mode to FULL_ASSET.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey for your quick answer, your second update answer my question and I will change the env mode to FULL_ASSET. One side question on this, At listener, Is there a way for me to get the accumulate kind of behavior ?. I am trying to find out how many resources assigned so far, based on that i need to give the next time grain.
Thank you,
Karthik

Comment: Currently I have the total assignment calculation in the rule (see below)
 when
       $timeGrain : TimeGrain($available : available);
        accumulate(
               $assigned : ServiceAssignment(timeGrain != null, timeGrain == $timeGrain);
               $totalAssigned : count($assigned);
               $totalAssigned > $available
        )
        then
          int tc = $totalAssigned.intValue();
           scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  ($available - tc) * 5   );      
end